# Upgrade SVN 1.6 to 1.7 on CentOS 5.5 with cPanel

Tags: svn, upgrade

So the answer seems to be to install over the existing version.
I took that to mean:

- download new version (1.7.2)
- configure
- make
- make install

Before the above process was run: svn --version --quiet prints 1.6.17
After the above process was run: svn --version --quiet prints 1.6.17  (should show 1.7.2)

What am I doing wrong here?

PS: SVN was installed initially using modified process described [here](http://sven.webiny.com/subversion-on-cpanel-3-with-centos-55-and-easyapache-32/). SVN is working right now, no problem, I just want to upgrade it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. I'm not sure why, but running svn --version --quiet indicates that I'm running 1.7.2 now.
I haven't restarted but I AM running a VPS, so maybe the guys at my host did something (not sure why they would, since I didn't ask them for any help).

If anyone else is having the same issues, and you are running CentOS and cPanel, please just follow the steps in the link provided in the OP, without doing the RPMForge stuff. Its a little out of date, and kind of obscure, but persistence and a lot googling on linux commands will get you there.